# How do I count the number of child entities with a specific value?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, parent-child

I have 2 entities in a to-many relationship, Parent-->Child. The Child entity has an boolean attribute which can be TRUE or FALSE.

I can easily count how many child entities there are with `[parent.child count]`, which returns a nice integer for me.

But what if I only want to count the child entities that are TRUE? Is there an easy way to do this?

---

### **EDIT**

I've tried to implement @unforgiven's predicate selection, but I'm getting an 'unable to parse the format string' error - this is the code I'm trying (where `Checklist` is the parent entity, `ChecklistItem` is the child entity, and `checked` is the bool value for the ChecklistItem):

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Checklist *aChecklist = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = aChecklist.name;

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Checklist" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(checklistItem, $sub, $sub.checked == %@).@count", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i items ticked", [results count]];
    [fetchRequest release];
}
```

If I replace the predicate with `any self.checklistItems.checked = %@` the the app doesn't crash, but the number returned is *the total number of Checklists that have any ChecklistItem checked*, which obviously means it returns the same number for every checklist.

Comment: Did you read my answer? Does it work for you?

Comment: @unforgiven Sorry - I wasn't at my computer most of yesterday. I had some trouble with it but in the course of reading more about predicates I came across `NSExpressionDescription` which may be what I'm after (I think it retrieves values rather than actual objects, which is all I need). I'm about to try it now...

Comment: @unforgiven - OK, couldn't get NSExpressionDescription to work. I think your predicate is a better idea :-)    ... Please see my comment under your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting a subset of only objects that are checked

```
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"checked = YES"]
NSSet *checkedChildren = [parent.children filteredSetUsingPredicate:filterPredicate];
NSUInteger count = [checkedChildren count];
```

Didn't double-check this before writing it out today, but I've written similar code on numerous occasions.

Spaced out over three lines for clarity.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! And far less code than the stuff I was trying. Just one thing: should the predicate be "checked == YES"? Seems to work fine either way, but I wanted to sure.

Comment: Um... maybe? The docs show using ==, but I think I've got both ways. Of course, I've also been writing a bunch of SQL lately, so I could be confusing the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a subquery in Core data. Assuming that the child entity has the boolean attribute called booleanAttribute, you need to fetch objects from the parent entity, using something similar to the following predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SUBQUERY(child, $sub, $sub.booleanAttribute == %@).@count", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

Comment: it crashes on the predicate line with the following error: `Unable to parse the format string "SUBQUERY(checklistItem, $sub, $sub.checked == %@).@count"` (obviously I've substituted in "checklistItem", which is my child entity, and "checked", which is the boolean attribute).

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with an alternative way of doing it. I've simply added an integer attribute called "numberChecked" to my parent entity ("Checklist"), and every time a ChecklistItem is ticked or unticked, I add or delete one from numberChecked.

```
if ([aChecklistItem checked] == [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]) {
    NSNumber *newCheckedNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[aChecklistItem.checklist.numberChecked floatValue] +1];
    aChecklistItem.checklist.numberChecked = newCheckedNumber;
}
else if ([aChecklistItem checked] == [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]) {
    NSNumber *newCheckedNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[aChecklistItem.checklist.numberChecked floatValue] -1];
    aChecklistItem.checklist.numberChecked = newCheckedNumber;
}
```

This works perfectly, but I'd still be interested to know if anyone can think of a way of doing it without having to explicitly add it to my data model.

Answer (score 0):

A few years later, this is now the easy way to do it.

You can use the @sum [collection operator](http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/) to easily count the objects in a collection with a YES BOOL value.

`[parent valueForKeyPath:@"children.@sum.checked"];`